# Why all the captured packet with libpcap in C++ have a length of zero?

Tags: c++, libpcap

I followed the steps mentioned [here](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html) to write a sample CPP program to capture my network adapter traffic and the final program that I compiled and run successfully is as below:

```
  1 #include <pcap.h>
  2 #include <stdio.h>
  3 #include <chrono>
  4 #include <thread>
  5 
  6 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  7 {
  8     pcap_t *handle;         /* Session handle */
  9     char *dev;          /* The device to sniff on */
 10     char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];  /* Error string */
 11     struct bpf_program fp;      /* The compiled filter */
 12     char filter_exp[] = "port 23";  /* The filter expression */
 13     bpf_u_int32 mask;       /* Our netmask */
 14     bpf_u_int32 net;        /* Our IP */
 15     struct pcap_pkthdr header;  /* The header that pcap gives us */
 16     const u_char *packet;       /* The actual packet */
 17 
 18     /* Define the device */
 19     dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
 20     if (dev == NULL) {
 21         fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't find default device: %s\n", errbuf);
 22         return(2);
 23     }
 24 
 25     fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dev);                                                                                    
 26 
 27     /* Find the properties for the device */
 28     if (pcap_lookupnet(dev, &net, &mask, errbuf) == -1) {
 29         fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't get netmask for device %s: %s\n", dev, errbuf);
 30         net = 0;
 31         mask = 0;
 32     }
 33     /* Open the session in promiscuous mode */
 34     handle = pcap_open_live(dev, BUFSIZ, 1, 1000, errbuf);
 35     if (handle == NULL) {
 36         fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open device %s: %s\n", dev, errbuf);
 37         return(2);
 38     }
 39     /* Compile and apply the filter */
 40     if (pcap_compile(handle, &fp, filter_exp, 0, net) == -1) {
 41         fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't parse filter %s: %s\n", filter_exp, pcap_geterr(handle));
 42         return(2);
 43     }
 44     if (pcap_setfilter(handle, &fp) == -1) {
 45         fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't install filter %s: %s\n", filter_exp, pcap_geterr(handle));
 46         return(2);
 47     }
 48 
 49     int x = 100;
 50     for(int i=0; i<30; i++){
 51         /* Grab a packet */
 52         packet = pcap_next(handle, &header);
 53         /* Print its length */
 54         printf("Jacked a packet with length of [%d]\n", header.len);
 55        
 56         std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(x));
 57     }
 58     /* And close the session */
 59     pcap_close(handle);
 60
 61     return(0);
 62 }
```

The problem is that, while my network adapter is selected correctly in the program, I only capture packets with len == 0!

```
ghasemi@ghasemi-MS-7693:~/Desktop/cpp_1$ g++ main.cpp -lpcap -std=gnu++11
ghasemi@ghasemi-MS-7693:~/Desktop/cpp_1$ sudo ./a.out 
enp5s0
Jacked a packet with length of [0]
Jacked a packet with length of [0]
Jacked a packet with length of [0]
Jacked a packet with length of [0]
Jacked a packet with length of [0]
Jacked a packet with length of [0]
Jacked a packet with length of [0]
Jacked a packet with length of [0]
Jacked a packet with length of [0]
Jacked a packet with length of [0]
Jacked a packet with length of [0]
Jacked a packet with length of [0]
Jacked a packet with length of [0]
Jacked a packet with length of [0]
Jacked a packet with length of [0]
Jacked a packet with length of [0]
Jacked a packet with length of [0]
Jacked a packet with length of [0]
Jacked a packet with length of [0]
```

My network configuration:

```
ghasemi@ghasemi-MS-7693:~/Desktop/cpp_1$ ifconfig 
enp5s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:cc:6a:0d:30:91  
          inet addr:192.168.1.170  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::fcb0:4105:1c21:4214/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7377903 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5250371 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10572328217 (10.5 GB)  TX bytes:363236585 (363.2 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:7403 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7403 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:2404900 (2.4 MB)  TX bytes:2404900 (2.4 MB)

vmnet1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:01  
          inet addr:172.16.66.1  Bcast:172.16.66.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:252 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vmnet8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:08  
          inet addr:192.168.18.1  Bcast:192.168.18.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:253 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compile a filter with `"port 23"`, which is the telnet port. You read just 30 packets with 100 ms pause in between. This amounts to only 3 seconds. And you don't check the return code of `pcap_next()`, which most likely returns `NULL`, see [pcap_next(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap_next)

> **Return Value**
>   ...
>   pcap_next() returns a pointer to the packet data on success, and returns NULL if an error occured, **or if no packets were read from a live capture**

So, I would guess, there is no traffic at all to telnet in these 3 seconds, and if you would check `packet`, there were no output, e.g.

```
/* Grab a packet */
packet = pcap_next(handle, &header);
/* Print its length */
if (packet != NULL)
    printf("Jacked a packet with length of [%d]\n", header.len);
```

Comment: What if I don't want any filter?

Comment: I don't know. But I guess, you will get all packages, no matter where they come from or what the destination is. Just try and leave out `pcap_compile` and `pcap_setfilter` and you will see.